# How to remove refresh token from OAuth call in RC

Tags: oauth-2.0, ringcentral

I am able to generate OAuth tokens from [this](https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/oauth/token) URL successfully.

However, I can see both refresh token and access token is generated in the call.

Can we remove the refresh token during the OAuth call so that only access token is generated.

I have seen this feature of suppressing and disabling refresh token in other OAuth servers.

Does it apply in RingCentral too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, refresh tokens can be disabled by setting the TTL (time to live) for the refresh_token_ttl to zero:

```
refresh_token_ttl=0
```

example:

```
username=<username>&password=<password>&extension=<extension>&grant_type=password&refresh_token_ttl=0
```

Comment: Where do I add this, using PHP API code and the password path?